# Moving search menu top right of page to left (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, search, grid

I am working on a WP site where I am trying to move the search menu in the top bar from the top right of the page all the way to the left. However the search bar is enclosed in a grid and I can only move to the left as far as the grid extends. Currently it is moved all the to the left of the grid which is the max it can move. The grid is also enclosed in a container. How can I move it out of the grid? Or anyway to get it to the left?

Website is:

http://museiam.ca/

Search bar CSS:

```
.gbtr_tools_search_trigger, .gbtr_tools_search_trigger_mobile, .gbtr_tools_search_inputbutton {
padding: 0 !important;
background: none !important;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 40px;
height: 30px;
border: 0;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2) !important;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2) !important;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
float: right;
}
```

Container & grid:

```
.container_12 .grid_6 {
text-align: left;
float: left;
}

.container_12 .grid_6 {
width: 460px;
}

.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12 {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this code to your stylesheet will solve the problem:

```
.gbtr_tools_search {
     float: right !important;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Please add this CSS to your stylesheet in order to move the search bar to the extreme left:

```
.container_12 .grid_6:first-child {
     display: none;
}

.container_12 .grid_6:nth-child(2) {
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello. I am actually an idiot. The search was originally to the all the way to the right like you have it now but I meant to say I wanted to move it all the way to the left. I edited my original, sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That made it much better :)